# How to change url stucture with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I  have this url `myurl.com/index.php?hello=folder/7f6c06`

I want to change it to `myurl.com/folder/7f6c06`

I tried

```
       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
       RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?hello=$1 [QSA,L]
```

is not working in godaddy hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because your pattern `([^/]+)` captures everything up to but not including the first `/`, but the URI you are looking to capture and pass into `hello=` includes a `/` itself. Since there are additional characters after the first `/` but the pattern matches at most one `/` optionally at the end, the pattern would never match as you have it.

Instead just use `(.+)/?` to capture *everything* up to an optional possible trailing slash.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?hello=$1 [QSA,L]
```